# Изменить строку по условию

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Задача в следующем: необходимо добавить в конец датафрейма строку, но если такая строка уже существует по индексу, то просто изменить значения ячеек этой строки на значения добавляемой строки.

Пример:

```
  A B C
K 1 2 3
L 1 3 5
M 2 5 3
```

Добавляем строку в конец:

```
df2 = DataFrame({'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'C': 6}, index=['N'])
df = df.concat(df, df2)
```

Получаем:

```
  A B C
K 1 2 3
L 1 3 5
M 2 5 3
N 2 3 6
```

Далее добавляем строку `DataFrame({'A': 2, 'B': 7, 'C': 7}, index=['N'])`, получаем:

```
  A B C
K 1 2 3
L 1 3 5
M 2 5 3
N 2 7 7
```

Проблема не в способе добавления , а в скорости этой операции, я пытался:

1. Проверить существует ли добавляемый индекс и если да, то просто изменить значения ячеек в оригинальном датафрейме функциями `at, set_value` - по скорости это очень дорого выходит, примерно 60мс
2. Просто приравнять по индексу новый датафрейм `df['N'] = [{'A': 2, 'B': 7, 'C': 7}]`, так же дорого, примерно 58мс
3. Каждый раз удалять строку по индексу, от датафрейма которого присоединяем `drop` и затем вызываем `df.concat(df, df2)` - получается просто нереально дорого 112мс
4. Если использовать просто `df.concat(df, df2)`, то это самый лучший вариант, примерно 6-7мс, но когда пытаешь присоединить новую строку, а в оригинальном датафрейме уже есть такая строка с индексом, то изменение значений не произойдет, тупо добавиться в конец еще одна строка и нет возможности прописать какие-либо условия в функции `concat`, чтобы не добавлялся новый индекс, а заменялся старый, новыми значениями в ячейках(столбцах)

Так вот вопрос, можно ли это сделать, чтобы работало по скорости как и `concat`, знаю что датафреймы не предназначены для редактирования, а только для анализа, но вдруг...

Comment: Подобный вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321939/pandas-update-record-if-exists
Правда о производительности там речи не шло

Comment: @immorom `merge` это вариант, хотя я смотрю там тоже нужно дополнительные телодвижения потом всё-равно делать )

Comment: Помимо `merge` еще есть `join`, но он не такой гибкий и может не подойти под задачу

Comment: @immorom, merge и join, такаже фигня как и loc, iloc - по времени, я их сразу откинул

Answer (score 3):

Могу предложить ещё несколько способов, быстрее которых вряд ли мне кажется можно что-то придумать. Какой будет быстрее и устроят ли они вас по скорости - это вы сами проверьте, у меня ведь нет ваших данных.

Подготовка примера данных, общая для последующих версий кода:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [4,5,6], 'C': [7,8,9]}, index=list('NMK'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2,3], 'B': [3,4], 'C': [6,7]}, index=['N','Q'])
```

Собственно сами способы:

1. - Выбираем в `df2` те индексы, которые есть и в `df`
   - "Векторно" присваиваем сразу по всем этим индексам в `df` новые значения из `df2`
   - Для остальных индексов из `df2` делаем конкатенацию значений `df` и `df2`

```
mask = df2.index.isin(df.index)
idx_set = df2.index[mask]
idx_concat = df2.index[~mask]
df.loc[idx_set] = df2.loc[idx_set]
df = pd.concat([df, df2.loc[idx_concat]])
```

2. - Выбираем индексы `df`, которых нет в `df2`
   - Конкатенируем только к части `df` согласно этих индексов датафрейм `df2`

```
idx_keep = df.index[~df.index.isin(df2.index)]
df = pd.concat([df.loc[idx_keep], df2])
```

Таким образом, в этом способе мы фактически удаляем из `df` предварительно совпадающие индексы перед конкатенацией, но мне кажется это будет быстрее, чем через отдельный `drop` (хотя тоже смотря как вы его делаете). Вот тоже самое через `drop`. Тут скорость будет зависеть от того, что возвращает `drop` - вью или новый датафрейм. Если вью, то, возможно, скорость будет как через `.loc`, но это нужно проверять:

```
idx_drop = df.index[df.index.isin(df2.index)]
df = pd.concat([df.drop(index=idx_drop), df2])
```

3. - Просто объединяем датафреймы
   - Для индексов-дубликатов выкидываем старые значения

```
df = pd.concat([df, df2])
df = df.loc[~df.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! По времени - дроп - 98мс, лок - те же 68мс - пожалуй, откажусь от данной операции, слишком дорого)))

Comment: @Duracell Хм, если `concat` настолько быстрее всего остального, то посмотрите 3-й способ, я сейчас добавил

Comment: третий вариант самый быстрый - 34-37 мс, я уже такой состряпал, но вы меня опередили,  `df = pd.concat([df if not df_newRow.index.isin(df.index) else df.iloc[:-1, :], df_newRow])` + у вас изящнее код получился

Comment: А нет, извиняюсь, ваш третий вариант 132мс))) - самый медленный, я так предполагаю, что из-за функции `dublicate`. В любом случае не тратьте время на этот вопрос - это бесполезно) на 7мс никак не выйти), как вы и говорили, так устроен пандас

Answer (score 1):

если буквально следовать тому что вы написали - *добавить в конец датафрейма строку, но если такая строка уже существует по индексу, то просто изменить значения ячеек этой строки на значения добавляемой строки*, то можно обойтись простым присвоением:

```
df.loc['N'] = [2,3,6]
df.loc['K'] = [2,7,7]

>>> df
'''
   A  B  C
K  2  7  7
L  1  3  5
M  2  5  3
N  2  3  6
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, такой вариант у меня описан в примере - он не подходит, тоже самое что и через loc, iloc

Comment: @Duracell, этот вариант выполняется за _108 µs ± 4.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)_, то есть 108 микросекунд, в вашем примере его не нашел

Comment: @ мой пример абстрактен, на самом деле я работаю с датафреймом 2млн+ строк.  Просто, чтобы люди меня поняли, я должен упростить все по максимуму. В моем примере прямое присвоение описано в п.2

Comment: @Duracell, ОК, просто я подумал, что вы для чего-то создаете колонку _df['N'] =_